# Move work in progress to another computer during git merge conflict

Tags: git

Beside using `cp` or something similar, is there a „git way“ of moving the work in progress of resolving a git merge conflict to another computer?

Comment: So you want to move the *local* code you have to work through the conflict to another machine?  Are the branches in conflict pushed to an upstream repository?

Comment: Yes and yes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no: the merging work you are doing is taking place in Git's index, plus your work-tree.  There's no "Git" way to send these to another repository on another computer.  (There should be, but is not.)

It is possible to make a transferable archive out of the entire work tree and `.git` directory and send that to another machine (or use `scp -r` or rsync or similar) to copy everything, including the index file(s).  However, the index itself contains machine-specific `stat` data, so this is not guaranteed to work.

Git needs some way to dump out the index into a transferable form (`git ls-files --stage`, more or less) and then read it back elsewhere (i.e., transfer any blobs missing on the other machine, along with this text dump) while also saving and restoring the work-tree state.  Ideally, there should be a way to turn all of this into a commit (that goes on no branch, a la stash commits), then "undo" it into the target machine.  That would also provide a way to save a partial merge and pick it up again later, with backup.  But it does not exist today.

Answer (score 0):

If the work you have is already pushed to an upstream repository, and the work conflicts with another upstream branch, then you don't have to copy anything across; have the other machine pull the existing branches and then attempt the merge.  That machine can then be used to resolve the conflict.

Comment: What happens to the uncommitted but resolved files on the first computer?

Comment: Nothing, so long as they're not pushed anywhere.

Comment: But I don’t want to lose the work already done on this computer and finish the merge conflict on the second one.

Comment: This will not work if got a hell amount of files, and provided you have resolved half of it.