# Git issues with visual studio project

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I am developing my project with git.

I use git extension for visual studio.

I have discovered that some of my code has not been applied correctly after pushes.

[image]

I only have a `master` branch, no other branches.

Every changes from the merge has not been applied when I do a pull from my second computer.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move work in progress to another computer during git merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119470/move-work-in-progress-to-another-computer-during-git-merge-conflict)

Comment: Yes thanks. I guess I will need to check everyfiles on my merge that went wrong...